# javascript doesn't immediately enable my button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use VS2010,C# for ASP.NET development, I've written a small Javascript function that enables an initially disabled button only after user inputs a phrase in a text box (this text box should not be empty), it works fine but there is a small problem, button is not enabled exactly when user types words, he should press tab or click on the screen so that button gets enabled! here is my JS function:

```
       <script type="text/javascript" >
       function onWeightChange() {
           document.getElementById('btnFinish').disabled = true;
           document.getElementById('btnConfirmQuestion').disabled = true;
           if (document.getElementById('txtWeight').value != "") {
               document.getElementById('btnFinish').disabled = false;
               document.getElementById('btnConfirmQuestion').disabled = false;
           }
       }
</script>
```

and I call my JS in codebehind in the following way:

```
            txtWeight.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return onWeightChange();");
```

what is going wrong here? I want my buttons to get enabled right after text is entered in textbox, and there should not be any need to change focus from textbox

thanks

Comment: use `onkeypress` instead of `onchange`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onchange` fires when the user leaves the element, it does not fire when the element has focus.

You need to use a key event, either `onkeypress` or `onkeyup` in combination with the `onchange` event. You need the `onchange` event since it is possible to change the value of the control without key presses!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct event you need to bind to is the keydown event as shown at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp or perhaps keyup depending on the behaviour you need.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks. I think the w3schools link still shows the details of the key events effectively, and correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the onkeyup method because onchange only fires when your textbox loses focus and in the case that someone pastes something into you textbox your should try the onpaste method this combination should work fine.

```
txtWeight.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "return onWeightChange();");
txtWeight.Attributes.Add("onpaste", "return onWeightChange();");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onchange()` event will only fire when the user leaves the input box.  You want to use the event `<input type="text" id="txtWeight" onkeyup="onWeightChange(this)" />`

```
<script type="text/javascript" >        
  function onWeightChange(el) {                             
      document.getElementById('btnFinish').disabled = e.value.length;                    
      document.getElementById('btnConfirmQuestion').disabled = el.value.length;    
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: paste text into the textbox with the the file menu, does your code now work?

Comment: hmm... good question.  Not sure if keyup applies to control keys.  Let me check it out and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, the onkeyup event is fired with ctrl-v, however, it can still be changed with right-click mouse, paste.  In those cases, you can keep the onchange event or add an onpaste event to the mix.